# Cannot resolve host name on most applications, but ping and browser succeeded

Tags: linux, dns, fedora-19

I have a weird problem where my browsers and ping can successfully resolve hostnames as per normal, but most other applications (ssh, git, pip, and even yum) cannot resolve hostnames.

What could be a possible cause for this?

I'm just upgraded to Fedora 19, perhaps something wrong in the recent firewall updates?

Comment: Please note that Fedora 19 reached end-of-life in January. Fedora 20 reached EOL last month. Currently-supported releases are 21 and 22.

Comment: @mattdm: Wah, thank you for the information. Will try to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's due to incorrect local DNS server.

Previously I had my local DNS server as the first DNS in NetworkManager. Removing it (disabling the auto DNS), and putting Google DNS (`8.8.8.8` and `8.8.8.4`) and then restarting NetworkManager (`sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`) solves the problem.

Comment: You may be interested in trying the experimental [system-local DNS resolver](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Default_Local_DNS_Resolver) feature that will go into Fedora 23. Among other things, this allows DNSSEC